# BASIC.js for toUpperCase

Tags: javascript

I'm going to go old school on JavaScript and write a BASIC.js that contains functions like:

```
function UCASE(obj) {
 return obj.toUpperCase();
}

function LCASE(obj) {
 return obj.toLowerCase();
}
```

Q: Has anyone done this already?

Comment: That... is disgusting.

Comment: Kinda similar to http://phpjs.org/

Comment: `REM What, no GOSUB, GOTO?  :)`

Comment: REM!  Added!  Now if only I could replace END for }

Comment: I want to see a Javascript translation of POKE.

Comment: function PRINT(text) { $('body').append(text); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://web.archive.org/web/20210301193936/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/vb2java.shtml

Answer (score 4):

Don't know that anyone has done that exactly -- honestly not sure of the utility, but hey, if it's fun for you, why not?

However, there are a number of javascript-based BASIC interpreters:

[NGBasic](http://www.ngbasic.com/)

[Quite BASIC](http://www.quitebasic.com/)

[Applesoft BASIC interpreter](http://www.calormen.com/applesoft/)

Comment: Wow!  That last one really took me back!