# VAL() function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

In continuing my [question from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454262/basic-js-for-touppercase), I have the following code:

```
function VAL(str) {
    // IF LEFT(str,1) IN('0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,.) THEN
    return parseFloat(str);
    return 0;
}

function LEFT(str,n) {
    if (n <= 0) return "";
    if (n >= str.length) return str;
    return str.substring(0,n);
}
```

Q: How do I write the commented line above such that it says "IF the first character is 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 or period, then return parseFloat(str)"?

Comment: Please rephrase your title as a question!  "How do I ensure my string is a number before using parseFloat?"  for example.

Comment: Capital function names makes programmers eyes bleed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need that check. If the first character is *not* a digit, then `parseFloat` returns `NaN`.

```
 function VAL(str) {
     var f = parseFloat(str);
     return isNaN(f) ? 0 : f;
 }
```

Comment: SIDE NOTE: `parseFloat("  60  ")` returns 60. So If you want that to return 0, my solution won't work -- you'll need to check the first character with `indexOf`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Regex

```
if (str.match(/([0-9]|\./)) return parseFloat(str);
```

Comment: i thought his . was a typo for the closing '

Answer (score 1):

set = "0123456789";
if (set.indexOf(LEFT(str, 1)) > -1 return parseFloat(str);